# Roadmap to rigid cohomology

Tags: reference-request, homology-cohomology, p-adic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

I am interested in the study of p-adic geometry. Unfortunately what I know is basic Algebraic geometry and basic number theory. To get an idea of the amount of material to study what could be a "roadmap" for reaching tools like rigid cohomology ?

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: I don't know anything about actual rigid cohomology, but if you're interested in getting to rigid analytic spaces I can recommend Siegfried Bosch's book *Lectures on Formal and Rigid Geometry,*